# Dynamic Increase / Decrease the number with C#

Tags: c#

I have two buttons to reduce or increase the number. Also, I have a label which is has value zero. How can I increase or decrease without giving zero value to the Label in C#?

Code:

```
int sayi = int.Parse(lbltext1.Text);

sayi = sayi - 1;

lbltext1.Text = sayi.ToString();
```

Comment: It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: Looks good to me.  I'd use sayi--; since it's more common and shorter.  What doesn't work about the code above?

Comment: Why don't you just get a beginners c# book and work through it, reading every page and answering every example question it has (if any).  That way you'll learn the language properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...(not tested)

```
void IncreaseBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = this.myLabel.Text;
    var intValue = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(value, out intValue);
    this.myLabel.Text = (++intValue).ToString();
}

void DecreaseBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = this.myLabel.Text;
    var intValue = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(value, out intValue);
    this.myLabel.Text = (--intValue).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store it as a member variable. Then increment/decrement it. Then set the `Label`'s `Text` property to the string version of the value.

Comment: +1 I thinks op will be clueless with this response.. but this is one of the many answer that can accomplish this...